# Derive the conditional distribution of $V_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ given $V_2 =\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2 $.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $(X_1, Y_1),..., (X_n, Y_n)$ be a random sample of size $n \geq 2$ from $(X,Y) \sim N_2 (0,0,1,1,\rho)$. Derive the conditional distribution of $V_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ given $V_2 =\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2 $.

My attempt: I know $V_1$ and $V_2$ follows from $\chi^2_n$ distribution. I don't know how to do next.

Comment: Where did this question come from? What do you know so far in relation to this problem? More effort shown would be nice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y,Z$ iid and $N(0,1)$ and $A,B,C$ such that
$M=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1-A&-B\\-B&1-C\end{array}\right]$ is positive definite.
Then $$E(e^{\frac{1}{2}(AZ^2+2BYZ+CZ^2)})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det M}}.\ \ \ (*)$$ Consequence, if $X=\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z+\rho Y$ we apply (*) to
$A=s(1-\rho^2),\ B=s\rho\sqrt{1-\rho^2},\ C=s\rho^2+t$  for computing
$$f_1(s,t)=E(e^{-sX^2/2-tY^2/2})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s+t(1+s(1-\rho^2))}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s}}\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+tr}}$$ with the notation $$r=\frac{1+s(1-\rho^2)}{1+s}$$Now if $(X_i,Y_i,Z_i)\sim (X,Y,Z)$ and $V_1=X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2,\ V_2=Y_1^2+\cdots+Y_n^2,\ V_3=Z_1^2+\cdots+Z_n^2,$ we are asked to find the conditional law of $V_1$ knowing $V_2.$ To  this end we consider $$f_n(s,t)=E(e^{-sV_1/2-tV_2/2})=(f_1(s,t))^n$$ which enables us to compute $$g(s,V_2)=E(e^{-sV_1/2}|V_2)$$ since $$f_n(s,t)=E(g(s,V_2)e^{-tV_2/2})=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-tv}g(s,v)\mu_{V_2/2}(dv)$$ or, since the law $\mu_{V_2/2}(dv)$ is known
$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s}}\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+tr}}\right)^n=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-tv}g(s,v)e^{-v}v^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\frac{dv}{\Gamma(n/2)}.$$
Finally since $t\mapsto f_n(s,t)$ can be also written as a Laplace transform :
$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s}}\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+tr}}\right)^n=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s}})^n\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tv}\frac{v^{\frac{n}{2}-1}}{r^{n/2}}\frac{dv}{\Gamma(n/2)},$$
we get $$g(s,v)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s(1-\rho^2)}}\right)^ne^{-\frac{v\rho^2 s}{1+s(1-\rho^2)}} $$ which is the Laplace transform of a non central chi square distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom. I can explain the parameters of the conditional distribution of $V_1$ knowning $V_2$ in terms of $V_2$ and $\rho$ if you  are not familiar with the non central chi square.

Comment: I am familiar with the non central chi square. But this method seems too complicated. Is there any easier way?

Comment: I would like too.

Comment: Have you an easier way? Not so many ways to describe a distribution: Laplace or Fourier transform, as above, or explicit calculation of the density. But remember that the density of a non central chi square is not elementary and is given by a series. Appearance of the non central chi square came as a surprise to me, and an intuitive explanation would be desirable. Thank for this elegant and difficult problem. What is its source?

Comment: What is the non-centrality parameter in the outcome?